# Creating model fires validation error with the newly created model - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

### The problem

Hey

I've been working with an issue for a few hours now and i am utterly baffeled by it.
Using a FormRequest in Laravel 7.4.0 i have the following validation rules, pay attention to the email:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\API\Auth;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class SignupRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'string|required',
            'email' => [
                'email',
                'unique:App\Models\User,email',
                'confirmed',
                'required'
            ],
            'password' => 'string|required|min:8|confirmed|',
            'security_question' => 'string|required',
            'answer' => 'string|required'
        ];
    }
}
```

And a function in a controller:

```php
public function signup(SignupRequest $request) {
    $securityQuestion = (new SecurityQuestion)->whereUuid($request['security_question'])->firstOrFail();

    if ($securityQuestion['answer'] !== $request['answer']) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Svaret var forkert'
        ], 401);
    }

    $request['password'] = Hash::make($request['password']);
    $request['activation_token'] = Str::random(60);

    $user = (new User)->create([
        'username' => $request['username'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => $request['password'],
        'activation_token' => $request['activation_token']
    ]);

    $avatar = (new Avatar)
        ->create($user->username)
        ->getImageObject()
        ->encode('png');

    Storage::disk('local')->put('public/avatars/' . $user->uuid . '/avatar.png', (string) $avatar);

    $user->notify(new ActivationEmail());

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully created user'
    ], 201);
}
```

Using this i've run into an issue, where out of nowhere i received this response:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "The email has already been taken."
        ]
    }
}
```

Data used, email changed between tries:

```
{
    "username": "username",
    "email": "nonactivated382@tester.dk",
    "email_confirmation": "nonactivated382@tester.dk",
    "password": "nonactivated2",
    "password_confirmation": "nonactivated2",
    "security_question": "a88a4e3a-78ae-4855-9630-053d606f94fa",
    "answer": "world"
}
```

Now i can tell you with 100% certainty the email has not already been taken, especially because the weird part is that the function executes, enters it into the database, sends the email and then it returns that error instead of success.

### What I've tried

- I changed the return point to be right before the User->create(), which returned no problem

  - Setting it right after causes the same issue
- Using the usual one line style for validation rules
- Specifying the table in the validation rules instead of model
- Using Arr::only to specify the different values of the model creation
- Just giving it the $request variable as input for model creation
- Using a different pc

  - Using a different database, and version
  - Using a different version of PHP
  - Using a different OS
- Using the Rule::unique() method
- Restarted development server, pc, database.
- Using $data = $request->validated(), and using the $data variable instead of straight $request
- Removing the email sending
- Commenting everything apart from model->create()

None of the above changed the issue, apart from the fact that the few last tries before deciding to make this post, the JSON under here was added to the response, still no clue why. Going back in removing and adding stuff does not change the outcome, so this is just permanently added as part of the issue:

```
"password": [
    "The password confirmation does not match."
]
```

It still creates the user and sends the email.

Now as far as i can figure out the issue seems to be that a validation error happens when creating the model. The weird part of that is that the unique validation rule, that is failing, is failing on the model it just allowed to go through, created and then it fails. Which as far as i know should not be possible in any way. Judging from the request lifecycle page in the documentation. There is nothing in the logs.

I hope some can help because i am completely lost as to what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm the password against the password_confirmation and also when validating unique you put the table name and not the model path. Try this

```
return [
            'username' => 'string|required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'string|required|min:8|',
            'password_cinfirmation' => 'string|required|min:8|same:password',
            'security_question' => 'string|required',
            'answer' => 'string|required'
        ];
```

Comment: Hi, thhanks for the answer, but i already tried that method. On top of that there is a the "confirmed" rule does exactly what you do manually. And there are 3 ways of doing unique, tried them all with no change.